python: сделать объект базы данных доступным отовсюду
Пишу десктопное приложение на Python. Использую класс Database такие файлы как user.py (для регистрации) и прочие файлы для записи остальных данных, из этого следует что мне нужно как-то отовсюду обращаться к одному объекту с разных файлов.
вопрос, как мне сделать так чтобы я к этому объекту мог обращаться с любого файла? Например закинуть в отдельный файл этот объект как будто бы фигня какая-то. Постоянно передавать его в параметрах как будто бы тоже такое себе. По-любому должен быть какой-то правильный способ

Посмотрите в сторону паттерна синглтон ‍♀️

я вот думаю просто в модуль объект закинуть, и от туда импортировать просто

Ну вообще "Постоянно передавать его в параметрах" это самое правильное, потому что явно прописывает зависимости между разными частями кода и таким образом облегчает дальнейшую его поддержку

Питон исполняет не файлы, а функции и другой код в них содержащийся. Переменная, ассоциированная с "объектом базы данных", должна быть доступна во всём приложении, в том числе и в содержащихся в нём функциях. Это достигается либо глобализацией "объекта", либо с помощью классов. У Вас серьёзнейшие проблемы с базовыми понятиями Питона. Рекомендую потратить таки время на штудирование хоть какого-нибудь учебничка. 90% подобных вопросов, надеюсь, рассосутся сами собой.
